# matplotlib colorbar in each subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I would like to add a separate colorbar to each subplot in a 2x2 plot.

```
fig , ( (ax1,ax2) , (ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2,sharex = True,sharey=True)
z1_plot = ax1.scatter(x,y,c = z1,vmin=0.0,vmax=0.4)
plt.colorbar(z1_plot,cax=ax1)
z2_plot = ax2.scatter(x,y,c = z2,vmin=0.0,vmax=40)
plt.colorbar(z1_plot,cax=ax2)
z3_plot = ax3.scatter(x,y,c = z3,vmin=0.0,vmax=894)
plt.colorbar(z1_plot,cax=ax3)
z4_plot = ax4.scatter(x,y,c = z4,vmin=0.0,vmax=234324)
plt.colorbar(z1_plot,cax=ax4)
plt.show()
```

I thought that this is how you do it, but the resulting plot is really messed up; it just has an all grey background and ignores the set_xlim , set_ylim commands I have (not shown here for simplicity). + it shows no color bars. Is this the right way to do it?

I also tried getting rid of the "cax = ...", but then the colorbar all goes on the bottom right plot and not to each separate plot!

Comment: Is `plt.colorbar(z1_plot,cax=ax2)`supposed to be `plt.colorbar(z2_plot,cax=ax2)`, etc for 3 and 4? For subplots and colorbars, I would look into [AxesGrid](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Please have a look at this [matplotlib example page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html). There it is shown how to get the following plot with four individual colorbars for each subplot: [image]

I hope this helps.
You can further have a look [here](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html), where you can find a lot of what you can do with `matplotlib`.

Comment: Another matplotlib example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html

Answer (score 71):

This can be easily solved with the the utility `make_axes_locatable`. I provide a minimal example that shows how this works and should be readily adaptable:

[image: bar to each image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

import numpy as np

m1 = np.random.rand(3, 3)
m2 = np.arange(0, 3*3, 1).reshape((3, 3))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 12))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
im1 = ax1.imshow(m1, interpolation='None')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(im1, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
im2 = ax2.imshow(m2, interpolation='None')

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
fig.colorbar(im2, cax=cax, orientation='vertical');
```

Answer (score 59):

In `plt.colorbar(z1_plot,cax=ax1)`, use `ax=` instead of `cax=`, i.e. `plt.colorbar(z1_plot,ax=ax1)`

Comment: to add: `fig.colorbar(sm, ax=fig.get_axes())` would add colorbar over both

Answer (score 48):

Specify the `ax` argument to [`matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html), e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
         data = np.array([[i, j], [i+0.5, j+0.5]])
         im = ax[i, j].imshow(data)
         plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax[i, j])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the func below to add colorbar:

```
def add_colorbar(mappable):
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    last_axes = plt.gca()
    ax = mappable.axes
    fig = ax.figure
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(mappable, cax=cax)
    plt.sca(last_axes)
    return cbar
```

Then you codes need to be modified as:

```
fig , ( (ax1,ax2) , (ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2,sharex = True,sharey=True)
z1_plot = ax1.scatter(x,y,c = z1,vmin=0.0,vmax=0.4)
add_colorbar(z1_plot)
```